# My first code does not work but my second code does. what is the problem in first one?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I am new to JavaScript. I am having a bit of a problem with my code. In code, I set an anonymous function in an addEventListener as an event function and it does not work.

```
 target.addEventListener("click", x); //it does not work//

 var x= function(event){   
   console.log(event.target);  
 };
```

But if I write the code like the second one then it works.

```
var y= function(){  
  target.addEventListener("click", x); //but it works// 
}  

var x= function(event){  
  console.log(event.target);  
};  

y();
```

I don't understand what is the problem with the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the function before assigning it to an event - as you did in your second example where y() is executed AFTER x is defined

```js
var x = function(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
};

// or
// const x = event =>  console.log(event.target);

const target = document.getElementById("butX");

target.addEventListener("click", x); //it does work//
```

```html
<button type="button" id="butX">Click</button>
```